# jQuery .html() or .text() not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a page in Joomla where the form loads on the fly(from the module). I have emptied the inner HTML contents of this form and inserted a content of my own to customize my forms.

Before emptying the contents of the original form, I have placed form elements in variables of their own:

```
var element1 = $('#e1').val();
var element2 = $('#e2').val();
```

Followed by the above lines, I have emptied the contents of the form and loaded new elements:

```
$('.originalform').empty();
$('.originalform').load("Location of my new file");
```

And finally, I inserted the the previously stored elements in my custom elements:

```
$('#newDiv').text(element1); // newDiv is a div element whose innerHTML should be element1
```

However, the newDiv element is not showing any value as expected.

Has it got to do with the DOM structure since it has been modified? Please assist.

Here you go guys. The HTML code:

```
<script>

                    var fname=$('#firstname').val();
                    var lname=$('#lastname').val();
                    var email123=$('#email').val();
                    var cname=$('#cb_companyname').val();
                    var city=$('#cb_city').val();
                    var bphone=$('#cb_businessphone').val();
                    var hphone=$('#cb_homephone').val();
                    var addr=$('#cb_address').val()+"\n"+city;
                    var postal=$('#cb_postalcode').val();
                    var mphone=$('#cb_mobilephone').val();
                    var altemail=$('#cb_alternateemail').val();
                    var country=$('#cb_country').val();
                    var name=fname+" "+lname; 
                    $('.cb_template_default').empty();//I empty a div that is within the form and load another content which is language dependant:
                    <?php if ($lang->getTag()=="en-GB") {?>
                    $('.cb_template_default').load('<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>templates/calderoni/edit-profile.php');
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    $('.cb_template_default').load('<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>templates/calderoni/edit-profile-it.php');

                //The new elements have new values inserted here.                   
                $(".newemail").text(email);
                $(".newname").text(name);
                $(".altemail").text(altemail);
                $(".bphone").text(bphone);
                $('.name').text(name);
                $('.altemail').text(altemail);
                $('.bphone').text(bphone);
                $('.hphone').text(hphone);
                $('.mphone').text(mphone);
                $('.cname').text(cname);

                $('.newaddr').text(addr);
                $('.postal').text(postal);
                $('.country').text(country); 
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the values of `element1` and `element2`? People should learn to debug more on SO...

Comment: It is #e1 and #e2 respectively. Sorry I missed that out.

Comment: @Hidde yes I did, and they are perfect.

Comment: can you post your mark up too?

Comment: is your `#newDiv` located within your form element `$('.originalform')`?

Comment: The HTML code, s'il vous plait :)

Comment: @FrancoisWahl Yes it is in the form element.

Comment: @MukundZare: In that case I'm surprised using the callback on the load method didn't make a difference. If `console.log(element1)` definetly shows the correct value and `$(#newDiv).html(element1)` also doesn't work than this nearly looks like some other code is clearing out the value again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these..

```
var element1 = $('e1').html();
var element2 = $('e2').html();
$('#newDiv').html(element1);
```

**EDIT**

```
var element1 = $('#e1').html();
var element2 = $('#e2').html();
$('#newDiv').html(element1);
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$('.originalform').load("Location of my new file");// populate form first
var element1 = $('#e1').val();// take value out
var element2 = $('#e2').val();
$('.originalform').empty();// and then empty
('#newDiv').text(element1);
```

Comment: i think your not loading the form first.

Comment: I am emptying the old form and loading a new one. Anyway, the values of elements from the old forms are safely being stored in the variables, which is what I am concerned with.

Answer (score -2):

You need to include `#` in your selector to query the elements by id.
So:

```
var element1 = $('#e1').val(); 
var element2 = $('#e2').val();
```

Comment: He just edited that in, read the comments to the question first. -1.

Comment: That was right at the same time then, I don't see why that should be -1. I'm trying to help here.

Comment: Also, it is not an answer. It is a comment.